# Can you add a user to multiple groups in one login?

Tags: onelogin

Can you add a user to multiple groups in one login?

Answer (score 1):

No. A user can only belong to one group max. In the UI you can only select one and via API you can only specify one group_id.

Comment: Conflicting answers: can you add a citation to your answer?

Comment: In the Admin select a user, go to authentication and you will see you can't only select 1 group.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. You can add a user to multiple groups at a time provided your application separates your Authorization logic.

For eg, If you have 3 groups i.e., Customer, Manager and Administrator then the customer must have a different login interface where only customers can login, the manager must have a different login interface where only managers can login and so on. This can be achieved but it consists of lot of code related tweaks to be done.

But the recommended approach is that to assign a user to one specific group and manage the permissions at group level.

Comment: Conflicting answers: can you add a citation to your answer?